# Not getting correct results with the increment operator in C++

Tags: c++

I am using the increment operator in prefix n postfix in C++, but i m getting incorrect results, can anyone please guide me n tell me what i m doing wrong :) Thank you :) 
here is my code :)

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 int a=0;
 cout<<a++<<endl<<++a<<endl;
 }
```

Expecting Result

```
 0
 2
```

but i m getting Result

```
 1 
 2
```

Comment: `a++` increments `a` and returns copy of it's value, which is 1. Nothing unexpected here.

Comment: Both uses are within one statement. You are assuming some kind of left-to-right order which is not correct.

Comment: @Jaa-c It returns copy of value before incrementing, which is (should be?) zero.

Comment: thank you Christian Hackl, Jaa-c,  stark

Comment: It's incredibly easy to run into undefined behaviour if you use `++` on the same object twice within the same expression. Even if the behaviour is well-defined, you still risk confusing yourself and future readers of your code. Do yourself a favour and split the expression: `std::cout << a++ << '\n'; std::cout << ++a << '\n';`

Comment: This is well-defined in C++17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the increment `operator++` and how it functions, depending if you use it as **prefix** or a **postfix**:

```
 #include <iostream>

 int main() {
    int a = 0;
    std::cout  <<  a++  << std::endl 
    // Output: 0. ++ as posfix creates an incremented copy of "a" and AFTER the line gets executed.
    std::cout  <<  ++a  << std::endl; 
    // Output: 1. ++ as prefix creates a copy of "a", an incremented copy BEFORE the line gets executed. 

    std::cout << a++ << std::endl << ++a << std::endl;
    // Output: 0
    //         1. 
    // "a" get incremented only by the prefix operator++
 }
```

---

Note: changed `using namespace std` and I [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) you use namespace+scope operator, like `std::` for C++ Standard Library containers.

Comment: thank you Santiago Varela :)

Comment: No prob @Romeo. Upvote please too :)

Comment: i upvoted :) , but bcoz i have less than 15 reputation,  getting message that it wont be shown